# WebDriver and GWT Suggest Boxes

Tags: gwt, selenium, webdriver, suggestbox

Ok...I give up :) 
What is the best way to select values out of a GWT Suggest Box using 
WebDriver? I'm using FirefoxDriver, and so far nothing seems to pick 
values out of a GWT suggestBox...not sendKeys, not selenium.keyUp, 
anything. 
I've even tried executing javascript directly to get those values to populate, like this (to no avail):

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('spSelect').value='verizon'");

Is there a better 
way? If not, what is the "best" way to get values out of a GWT suggest 
Box? 
Many thanks in advance. 
Cheers 
Pedro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, we've figured out our problem. 
We were setting explicit IDs on our elements, so our tests can grab 
them easier. In GWT this is done via:

```
usernameLabel.getElement().setId("consoleLoginPageUserNameInput");
```

This works fine for most GWT inputs, but for the SuggestBox it is 
handled a bit differently:

```
spSelect.getElement().getElementsByTagName("input").getItem(0).setId("spSelect");
```

After grabbing the correct inner table, we are able to interact with 
this input with Selenium just fine. Hope this helps someone. 
Cheers 
Pedro

Answer (score 0):

Try this javascript ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933836/gwt-trouble-getting-value-from-a-text-box)):

To set the value:

```
document.getElementById("spSelect")["value"] = "verizon"
```

To retrieve it:

```
var value = document.getElementById("spSelect")["value"];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply...however no luck. I know you can use javascript directly to set the values of inputs, but it seems the GWT SuggestBox is not an input per se.

Comment: You must have a different version or fork of the GWT SuggestBox - it worked on every one I tried it with.  Either way, I feel your pain, these custom UI controls are a pain to automate.